# Hanging Drywall Around a Door

Tags: drywall, screws

Easy question. I'm hanging drywall around a doorway. Do I put screws in both the jack and king studs or only one? For studs in the field, it's straight forward. But, for the doorway, where the jack and king are right next to each other, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you will have an issue with either place that you locate them. However in the jack studs you are next to the door and your door casing and fit might be cleaner / easier - no bulges ripples waves etc. just a nice smooth straight surface for your casing.